# SQL JOIN returning both tables in single column

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I do a SQL JOIN returning both tables in single column?

For example, for a given group ID, how do I obtain a single list of all people who belong to that group plus all their friends?

groups

```
-id
-name
```

groups_have_people

```
-groups_id
-people_id
```

people

```
-id
-name
-group_id
```

people_have_friends

```
-people_id1 (references people.id)
-people_id2 (references people.id)
```

For instance, `groups_have_people` includes `people_id` 1, 2, and 3 for group 123, and `people_have_friends` includes records `1-2`, `1-3`, `1-4`, `2-1`,`2-5`, I should get the following results:

```
id Name
1  Mary
2  John
3  Burt
4  Jill
5  Sue
```

I can do something like the following, but it doesn't return a single list.

```
SELECT p1.*, p2.*
FROM people p1
INNER groups_have_people ghp ON ghp.people_id=p1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN people_have_friends phf ON p1.id=phf.people_id1
LEFT OUTER JOIN people p2 ON p2.id=phf.people_id2
WHERE ghp.groups_id=123;
```

**EDIT**  Looks like maybe I don't use a JOIN to do so, and should do something like the following?

```
SELECT p.*
FROM people p
INNER groups_have_people ghp ON ghp.people_id=p.id
WHERE ghp.groups_id=123
UNION
SELECT people p1
INNER JOIN people_have_friends phf ON p1.id=phf.people_id1
INNER JOIN people p2 ON p2.id=phf.people_id2
WHERE p2.groups_id=123;
```

**EDIT 2.  Add more sample data**

Groups

```
id  name
111 Green
123 Blue
222 Yello
```

People

```
id Name
1  Mary
2  John
3  Burt
4  Jill
5  Sue
6  Bob
7  Wilma
```

groups_have_people

```
groups_id  people_id
111        1
111        5
123        1
123        2
123        3
222        3
222        7
```

people_have_friends

```
people_id1  people_id2
1           2
1           3
1           4
2           1
2           5
4           5
5           6
```

**EDIT 3.  What about something like the following?**

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
                name
FROM people
WHERE id IN
    ( SELECT people_id
     FROM groups_have_people
     WHERE groups_id=123
     UNION SELECT phf.people_id
     FROM people_have_friends phf
     INNER JOIN groups_have_people ghp ON ghp.people_id=phf.people_id
     WHERE ghp.groups_id=123);
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
                name
FROM people
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT people_id
   FROM groups_have_people
   WHERE groups_id=123
   UNION SELECT phf.people_id
   FROM people_have_friends phf
   INNER JOIN groups_have_people ghp ON ghp.people_id=phf.people_id
   WHERE ghp.groups_id=123) x ON x.people_id=people.id;
```

Comment: that is very good, you provided expected results, but could you provide data raw source then? so we can see where and how that results come from. the best way is to start from providing a fiddle like this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bc438

Comment: @Alex  I had included the following in the original post.  Is this not adequate?  Thanks `For instance, groups_have_people includes people_id 1, 2, and 3 for group 123, and people_have_friends includes records 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-1,2-5, I should get the following results:`

Comment: you did not provide all tables samples

Comment: @Alex  Please see bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89a12/3

```
SELECT 
  p.id,
  p.name
FROM groups_have_people ghp
INNER JOIN people p 
ON ghp.people_id=p.id
WHERE ghp.groups_id=123
UNION
SELECT 
  p.id,
  p.name
FROM groups_have_people ghp
INNER JOIN people p_temp 
ON ghp.people_id=p_temp.id
INNER JOIN people_have_friends phf 
ON p_temp.id=phf.people_id1
INNER JOIN people p 
ON phf.people_id2=p.id
WHERE ghp.groups_id=123
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Could it be optimized? I added a couple of untested possibilities? (couldn't get the sql fiddle working).  Thanks